# localOrientationMatrixToHeadingTiltRoll function in google earth not working correctly

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, google-earth-plugin

In playing with the milk truck game, I think I may have found an error or maybe it is an error in my understanding.  In the truck.js or car.js depending on which version you are looking at right after the line that looks like this which is around line #396:

```
absRoll += me.roll;
```

I add the following line.

```
console.log ('heading current at end = ' + this.model.getOrientation().getHeading());
console.log('heading at end set to = ' + newhtr[0]);
```

When I do this I get the following output:

> heading current at end = 90
>  heading at end set to =
>   116.62015241568602

Now be default the heading is set to 90 in the code and if I haven't hit any of the turn keys. Why would the heading be getting set to 116 here then?

I can only assume that there is either something wrong with the way we are initially setting the modelMatrix or there is something wrong with the localOrientationMatrixToHeadingTiltRoll method.
Does it have something to do with local or global coordinate systems used?

In any case, can anyone shed some light on this for me.

Thanks,

Comment: link to the presumed example - http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/milktruck/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simply because once the milk-truck hits the road it gets turned very slightly. If you look at the example the car loads in mid-air heading 90 - then 'hits the virtual tarmac' and is turned because of the slight slope in the terrain.